# Why isn't the ship moving right but goes left, up and down (the unoptimized way)?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

```
class Ship():

    def __init__(self, ai_setting, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_setting = ai_setting
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/ship.bmp")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (200, 200))

        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()

        self.image_rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.image_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx

        self.center_xaxis =float( self.image_rect.centerx)
        #move_flags
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.moving_down = False


    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.center_xaxis += self.ai_setting.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left:
            self.image_rect.centerx -= 10
        if self.moving_up:
            self.image_rect.centery -=10
        if self.moving_down:
            self.image_rect.centery +=10

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.image_rect)
```

I tried printing the value of `self.center_xaxis` and `self.image_rect.centerx`
but `self.center_xaxis` isn't the same.

I need the value of `self.center` to change by a factor I'll control in the settings file I made. The `game_function` file handles the changing movement flags according to the keypress to `True` or back to `False`.

Comment: All the directions that work modify `self.image_rect.centerx`, update the same attribute when moving right? What do you mean by the unoptimised way, why would updating `self.center_xaxis` be "optimised"?

Comment: Nothing (in the code you posted, at least) actually uses `self.center_xaxis` - so changing it has no effect.

Comment: @jasonharper I believe this was the dumbest oversight that made me scratch my head for hours. Thank you so much

Comment: @IainShelvington I used the wrong term. I mean Refactored way. I am refactoring my code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to move the object with floating point precision. Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data. See [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html):

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

If you want to store object positions with floating point accuracy, you have to store the location of the object in separate variables respectively attributes and to synchronize the `pygame.Rect` object. [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) the coordinates and assign it to the location of the rectangle:

```py
 class Ship():

    def __init__(self, ai_setting, screen):
        # [...]

        self.center_xaxis = self.image_rect.centerx
        self.center_yaxis = self.image_rect.centery

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.center_xaxis += self.ai_setting.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left:
            self.center_xaxis -= self.ai_setting.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_up:
            self.center_yaxis -=10
        if self.moving_down:
            self.center_yaxis +=10

        self.image_rect.centerx = round(self.center_xaxis)
        self.image_rect.centery = round(self.center_yaxis)

    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.image_rect)
```